# Email from TLD .pl not getting processed by our Exchange 2003 server

Tags: exchange-2003

I am trying to research a problem with email from the TLD .PL not getting processed by our Exchange 2003 server.  There is no record of the email in Message Tracking Center.  We have a Barracuda Spam appliance - I see the message there so I know it gets to us.  If I freeze the Messages pending submission queue it never shows up.  This holds true even if I open a Telnet session and enter the email by hand.  No error messages show up in the Telnet session - it looks like it goes through, however it does not.

Any troubleshooting tips?  Perhaps the Message pending submission is not the correct queue to be looking in?

Answer (score 0):

So you're receiveing email for a .PL TLD, meaning your Exchange server should be authoratative for and accept email for this .PL TLD? If that's the case, have you added the domain inquestion (domain.PL) to your Recipient Policy?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a prior admin created a Sender Filtering rule (located in System Manager Global Settings/Message Delivery/Properties) `*@*.pl`  They checked the option *Accept messages without notifying sender of filtering* and unchecked *Archive filtered messages* which effectively hid this action from the sender and us.